# writing output to a excel in different column

Tags: excel, file, recursion, tcl

Hi I am using tcl to write output a xls file.
however I am succeeding in writing the output to a xls file in one column but what i want to split and write to two different column at the sane time .
My code which is writing to one column only is working fine:

```
 set fh [open $e w]
  while {[llength $c]} {
    set name [lindex $c 0]
    set c [concat [glob -nocomplain -directory [lindex $c 0] -type d *] [lrange $c 1 end]]
    set filesofDirectory [glob -nocomplain -directory $name -type f *]

        if { [llength $filesofDirectory] > 0 && $d == "fftc"} {
                set x "number of files in $name is  [llength $filesofDirectory]"


                puts $fh [join $x ]
        } 
    }
    close $fh
```

However when I modified the same code to have the output :

```
 set fh [open $e w]
  while {[llength $c]} {
    set name [lindex $c 0]
    set c [concat [glob -nocomplain -directory [lindex $c 0] -type d *] [lrange $c 1 end]]
    set filesofDirectory [glob -nocomplain -directory $name -type f *]

        if { [llength $filesofDirectory] > 0 && $d == "fftc"} {
                set x "number of files in $name"
                set y [llength $filesofDirectory]

                puts $fh [join $x "," $y]
        } 
    }
    close $fh
```

Please suggest the workaround

Comment: Your invocation of `join` in the second example is incorrect. You do not give enough information to understand either your code or what exact problem you are experiencing.

Comment: the requirement is to write output, say "number of files in d:/folder1 is 4" to an excel spreadsheet. It is working fine with the first snipet as it is writing it to only one column what i want is to write the number part , say 4 to  a different column that is second column and "number of files in d:/folder1 is " in first column for which the second example of snippet is not working ...

Comment: That is still just the requirement or expectation. Again, I presume the incorrect invocation of `join` is the root of the problem, but since you aren't telling us what the problem is (apart from the fact that it isn't working) it's hard to be sure. In any case, if you are creating Excel documents in CSV format (which seems to be the case: you aren't telling us if this is true) you should be using the `csv` module instead of `puts` statements.

Comment: yes you are right. I am creating excel documents in csv format...how could i go ahead?

Comment: ok no issue I have created the csv file and then convert it to excel sheet using code in perl. Thanks hoodie for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dump a directory breakdown into a CSV file that can be used in Excel, this code ought to work:

```
package require csv

set c .
set d fftc
set e foo.csv

proc glob2csv {c d fh} {
    foreach name $c {
        if {[file isdirectory $name]} {
            set n [llength [glob -nocomplain -directory $name -type f *]]
            if {$n > 0 && $d eq "fftc"} {
                chan puts $fh [csv::join [list "number of files in $name is" $n]]
            }
            glob2csv [glob -nocomplain -directory $name -type d *] $d $fh
        }
    }
}

try {
    open $e w
} on ok fh {
    glob2csv $c $d $fh
} finally {
    catch {chan close $fh}
}
```

I'm making a lot of uncomfortable assumptions here since I don't really know what your code is about. You might want to use the optional arguments to `csv::join` to tweak the format of the CSV file. In my locale, for instance, I need to set the separator character to tab (`\t`) to avoid having Excel treat every line as a single string.

Documentation for the [Tcllib CSV module](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html)

Documentation: [catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm), [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [glob](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [try](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.htm)